# python: open and read a file containing german umlauts as unicode

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode, utf-8, diacritics

I have written my program to read words from a text file and enter them into a sqlite database and also treat them as strings. But I need to enter some words containing German umlauts: `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, `ß`.

Here is a prepared piece of code:

I tried both with # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*- and # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    No difference(!)

```
    # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
    import sqlite3
    
    dbname = 'sampledb.db'
    filename ='text.txt'


    con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''create table IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name)''')    

    #f=open(filename)
    #text = f.readlines()
    #f.close()

    text = u'süß'

    print (text)
    cur.execute("insert into table1 (id,name) VALUES (NULL,?)",(text,))       

    con.commit()

    sentence = "The name is: %s" %(text,)

    print (sentence)
    f.close()
    con.close()
```

the above code runs well. But I need to read 'text' from a file containing the word 'süß'. So when I uncomment the 3 lines ( f.open(filename) .... ), and commenting **text = u'süß'** it brings the error

```
    sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I tried codecs module to read a utf-8, iso-8859-15. But I could not decode them to the string 'süß' which I need to complete my sentence at the end of the code.

Once I tried decoding to utf-8 before inserting into the database. It worked, but I could not use it as string.

Is there a way I can import süß from a file and use it both for inserting to sqlite and using as string?

---

more detail:

Here I add more details for clarification. I have used `codecs.open` before.
The text file containing the word *süß* is saved as `utf-8`. Using `f=codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8')` and `text=f.read()`, I read the file as unicode `u'\ufeffs\xfc\xdf'`. Inserting this unicode in *sqlite3* is smoothly done: `cur.execute("insert into table1 (id,name) VALUES (NULL,?)",(text,))`.

The problem is here: `sentence = "The name is: %s" %(text,)` gives `u'The name is: \ufeffs\xfc\xdf'`, and I also need to `print(text)` as my output *süß*, while `print(text)` brings this error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`.

Thank you.

Comment: The coding parameter *should* have made a big difference in your `text` literal.

Comment: to clarify: the coding declaration at the top of the module affects `text = u'süß'` specified in the source code. It has *no effect* on the text read from the file. You could use `codecs.open()` for the latter.

Comment: `readlines` returns a list. Use `f.read().strip()` to get the text of the file as a string. _Then_ you can start worrying about encodings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could sort out the problem. Thanks for the helps.

Here it is:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import sys 
import codecs
import sqlite3

f = codecs.open("suess_sweet.txt", "r", "utf-8")    # suess_sweet.txt file contains two
text_in_unicode = f.read()                          # comma-separated words: süß, sweet 
f.close()

stdout_encoding = sys.stdout.encoding or sys.getfilesystemencoding()

con = sqlite3.connect('dict1.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''create table IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,German,English)''')    

[ger,eng] = text_in_unicode.split(',')

cur.execute('''insert into table1 (id,German,English) VALUES (NULL,?,?)''',(ger,eng))       

con.commit()

sentence = "The German word is: %s" %(ger,)

print sentence.encode(stdout_encoding)

con.close()
```

I got some help from [this page](http://gelb.bcom.at/trac/misc/wiki/TutorialsPython/PythonUmlauteUnicodeEncodings) (it's in German)

and the output is:

```
The German word is: ?süß
```

Still a small problem is the '?'. I thought that the unicode `u'` is replaced by `?` after encoding. `sentence` gives:

```
>>> sentence
u'The German word is: \ufeffs\xfc\xdf '
```

and encoded sentence gives:

```
>>> sentence.encode(stdout_encoding)
'The German word is: ?s\xfc\xdf '
```

so it was not what I thought.

A simple solution comes to my mind, to get rid of the question mark is to use the **replace** function:

```
sentence = "The German word is: %s" %(ger,)
to_print = sentence.encode(stdout_encoding)
to_print = to_print.replace('?','')

>>> print(to_print)
The German word is: süß
```

Thank you SO :)

Answer (score 7):

When you open and read a file, you get 8-bit strings not Unicode. In Python 2 to get a Unicode string instead use [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to open the file:

```
f=codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8')
```

Hopefully though you've moved on to Python 3, where the encoding was put into the regular [`open` call](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data).  Also unless you open with the `'b'` flag for binary, you'll always get Unicode strings not 8-bit binary strings and a default encoding will be used if you don't specify one.

```
f=open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Of course depending on how the file was written you may need to use `'iso-8859-15'` instead.

Edit: one *big* difference between your test code and the commented out code is that reading from the file produces a list, while the test is a single string. Perhaps your problem isn't related to Unicode at all. Try making this substitution in your test code and see if it produces the same error:

```
text = [u'süß']
```

Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with SQL in Python to help you further.

Also when you print a `list` instead of a single string, the Unicode characters will be replaced with their equivalent escape sequences. To see what the strings really look like, print them one at a time. If you're curious it's the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`.

Edit 2: The character `u'\ufeff'` is known as a [Byte Order Mark or BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and is inserted by some editors to indicate that the file is truly UTF-8. You should get rid of it before you use the string. There should only be one at the very beginning of the file. See e.g. [Reading Unicode file data with BOM chars in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590749/reading-unicode-file-data-with-bom-chars-in-python)

Comment: I added more details to the question.

Comment: @Amin, next time you tell somebody you've added details to the question, do it **after** your edit. I completely missed it before I did my own edit.

Comment: Using 'iso-8859-15' instead of utf-8 worked for me, thanks for that tip!

Comment: @Uzebeckatrente because of the way `iso-8859` is structured, it won't generate an error on any input.  But that doesn't mean you're getting the proper characters, you should double-check for that.

Comment: I did some random checks, looked ziemlich schön :)