# How to get Python to recognize German symbols, like umlaut?

Tags: python, unicode

I was reading this: [python: open and read a file containing germanic umlaut as unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137613/python-open-and-read-a-file-containing-germanic-umlaut-as-unicode)

I'm reading my dataframe from a CSV file, using `pd.read_csv()`

The `\x9f` should be an umlaut:

```
'Heiner Dr\x9fke "Weil, Gotshal & Manges"'
```

I tried to no avail:

```
person1.encode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

TRIED

```
I get this when i use macroman person1.decode('macroman')
Out[511]:
u'Heiner Dr\xfcke "Weil, Gotshal & Manges"'
```

However, when I print `person1.decode('macroman')` does print out the umlaut.
How do I capture this into a string?

```
person1.decode("cp1251")
Out[512]:
u'Heiner Dr\u045fke "Weil, Gotshal & Manges"'
```

Comment: have you tried using https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html?

Comment: `decode("cp1252 ")` work?

Comment: no it is macroman encoding ... bad ... not sure how he got that encoded like that

Comment: read http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/760326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

somehow you are encoded to macroman ... you shouldnt be

```
>>> print 'Heiner Dr\x9fke "Weil, Gotshal & Mages"'.decode("macroman")
Heiner Drüke "Weil, Gotshal & Mages"
```

this will decode it to unicode that python understands ...

if you want to encode it for a google search

```
'Heiner Dr\x9fke "Weil, Gotshal & Mages"'.decode("macroman").encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

should work fine

Comment: I get this when i use macroman person1.decode('macroman') 
Out[511]:
u'Heiner Dr\xfcke "Weil, Gotshal & Manges"'

Comment: You have to `print person1.decode('macroman')` to see the character in Python 2.X.  `u'\xfc'` is the Unicode hex escape character for `ü`.

Comment: is there a way to capture the 'ü' for search? I'm trying to use that string to search on google, but I can only use 'Dr\xfcke'

Comment: see update answer that should give you a path forward ... you did not specify that criteria however in your initial question... but this method should work fine

Comment: cause I googled umlaut \x9f and found it to be that encoding ... it encodes it to ascii using xml character replacement on any non-ascii characters ... in otherwords it just works ;P

Answer (score 1):

`u = u"profileDir_(\u00fc)"`  (u umlaut)  according to this [reference](http://lists.osafoundation.org/pipermail/chandler-dev/2006-April/005718.html)

Comment: I dont think this really answers his question ... his string is encoded as macRoman ... when properly decoded he does get his desired unicode result