# while reading json file in python some additional unicode symbols appear in the data

Tags: python, json, unicode

I need to get data from json file to further send it in the post-request. Unfortunately, when i read the file, some unexplained unicode symbols at the beginning

```
path = '.\jsons_updated'
newpath = os.path.join(path, 'Totem Plus eT 00078-20140224_060406.ord.txt')
file = open(newpath, 'r')
#data = json.dumps(file.read())
data = file.read()
print('data= ', data)
file.close()
```

Data in the file starts with this:

```
{"PriceTableHash": [{"Hash": ...
```

I get the result:

```
data=  п»ї{"PriceTableHash": [{"Hash": ...
```

or in case of data = json.dumps(file.read())

```
data=  "\u043f\u00bb\u0457{\"PriceTableHash\": [{
```

So my request can't process this data.
Odd symbols are the same for all the files i have.

UPD:
If i copy data manyally in the new json or txt file, problem dissappears. But i have about 2,5k files, so that's not an option =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `open(newpath, 'r')` opens the file with your system's default encoding (whichever that might be). So when you read encoded Unicode data, that will mangle the encoding (so instead of reading the UTF-8 encoded data with a UTF-8 decoder, Python will try Cp-1250 or something).

Use `codecs.open()` instead and specify the correct encoding of the data (i.e. the one which was used when the files were written).

The odd bytes you get look like a [BOM header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You may want to change the code which writes those files to omit it and send you pure `UTF-8`. See also [Reading Unicode file data with BOM chars in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590749/reading-unicode-file-data-with-bom-chars-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! [Reading Unicode file data with BOM chars in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590749/reading-unicode-file-data-with-bom-chars-in-python) helped. If i open my files like this: `file = codecs.open(newpath, 'r', 'utf-8-sig')`, everything is ok.