# How to open text documents in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a text document in notepad. The encoding is UTF-8. I have saved the text document as bradley.
I want to read the document using python 3.4
here is my code:

```
doc=open("bradley.txt","r",encoding="UTF-8")
doc.readlines()
doc.close()
```

I get the error.TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
I removed the "r" so that my code is`doc=open("bradley.txt",encoding="UTF-8")`
when i run it...The IDLE gives me nothing. what i was expecting is that i get the contents of the file. How can i achieve that?

Comment: As I remember notepad adds [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the UTF-8 files. Does Python `readlines()` have a parameter to skip them when found?

Comment: The "r" is for read-only, so it shouldn't have any effect here. You should put here the actual code and the error, this code doesn't require any integer.

Comment: the error and the code are above

Comment: Your code for reading the file seems correct, so the problem must be in the file and/or notepad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Unicode file data with BOM chars in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590749/reading-unicode-file-data-with-bom-chars-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename the ending to .py and import it, like so:

```
from bradley import *
```

I have a platformer which scrolls the screen, and I have a function in a separate document called player.py. I can call that function from withing the main program by using `from player import Player`  at the beggining of the code (where Player is the function).

Comment: please just write an example of a code that reads a text document

Comment: Is the text document something that you want to take a separate chunk of code from, or what kind of information are you trying to get from it? Could you post the text document?

Comment: the text document just contains...random names...just wanted  to know how to use the open function

Comment: I don't know about that one... sorry.