# Sqlalchemy read query from file on Windows

Tags: python, windows, encoding

I want to read a table from a query script in my computer.
I found the command to be simple:

```
with open(sql_file, 'r') as opened:
  query = alq.text(opened.read())
```

The first issue, has to do with encoding:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 
in position 7963: character maps to <undefined>
```

So we do what we do, search for an answer to add argument into command `open(sql_file, encoding='utf8')` and execute the query.

```
engine.execute(query)
```

And now the error is more tricky:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Incorrect syntax near '\ufeff'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") 
[SQL: "\ufeffWITH\n-- Some comment about the query\nQC_SCORE AS 
(\n  SELECT some_table.id\n  , other_table.column\n
```

That is to not be reading the file correctly.  Upon inspection I found that there is `\ufeff` at the beginning of the file and that the line breaks `\n` are not being translated.

Does anyone know how to go about it?

Comment: Can you execute the entire raw query with engine.execute? You have to manually handle the unicode chars like `ufeffWITH` here

Comment: FEFF at the beginning of a file looks like BOM, or byte order mark. UTF-8 with BOM is a Microsoft bastardisation, since UTF-8 is an 8-bit codec and does not need BOM. Try using the utf-8-sig codec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590749/reading-unicode-file-data-with-bom-chars-in-python/13591421, https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode

Comment: ¡¡¡Ahhh!!!    Yes. Thanks @IljaEverilä. I spent hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while trying to parse an XML file that had special unicode characters.  What I found as a viable workaround was just reading the file as a string, then using the string.replace() method.  Something along this line:

text_query = r"\ufeff + "actual SQL code"
text_query = text_query.replace(r'\ufeff', '').replace(r'\n', '')