# Unable to read file as plain text

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a powershell script which im trying to read in and do some analysis on it. I'm able to read it only as bytes and not as plain text.

```
f=open('~/Data/3 - Get-Services - Jobs Version 1.0.ps1','r')
txt=f.read()
```

When i try the above code, im thrown an error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

So, I tried reading it as bytes and then decode it to plain text but but i'm still thrown the error.

```
f=open('~/Data/3 - Get-Services - Jobs Version 1.0.ps1','rb')
txt=f.read()
txt.decode('utf-8')
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

I looked up the data on command line and i noticed that all the files start with "��". I feel this charachter is causing the problem but i do not know how to solve this issue.

Could you please help

Comment: It is not encoded as utf-8.

Comment: I tried that too but, the problem still persists

Comment: *No*. I said UTF-8 is *not what the file is encoded in*. Try another encoding. It looks like that is a BOM,  try `'utf-8-sig'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)

Comment: Hi, try using `utf-16` for decoding as the above duplicate suggests in an answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, sorry for misreading your initial comment. I changed the encoding to `'utf-8-sig'` but it still doesnt work

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, thanks for the answer! changing the encoding type to `utf-16` works! thanks you!

Comment: @SridharMurali I wrote this as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cite the answer from Peter Ogden from [error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in) (not the accepted answer) .

> I've come across this thread when suffering the same error, after
>   doing some research I can confirm, this is an error that happens when
>   you try to decode a UTF-16 file with UTF-8.
>
> With UTF-16 the first characther (2 bytes in UTF-16) is a Byte Order
>   Mark (BOM), which is used as a decoding hint and doesn't appear as a
>   character in the decoded string. This means the first byte will be
>   either FE or FF and the second, the other.
>
> Heavily edited after I found out the real answer

So, changing to `UTF-16` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: despite four upvotes, my guess was **wrong**. In UTF-8 encoding, the BOM would look like `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`, so the first byte is `0xEF` and not `0xFF`.

`0xFF,0xFE` would signify the start of a little-endian UTF-16 file. Use the `utf-16` encoding for that!

---

My guess is that the two "unknown" characters at the start are a [Unicode BOM (byte-order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

If that's the case, decode with [`utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44573867/14637). There's no need to read as bytes first; you can pass an `encoding` to the `open()` function directly:

```
f = open('~/Data/3 - Get-Services - Jobs Version 1.0.ps1', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: @SridharMurali That's because I made a mistake, see my edit!