# Python json decode error when opening a basic json file

Tags: python, json, decode

I have an issue opening a pretty basic json file just as a test and I am getting the following output:

```
\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the python code:

```
import json

with open('test1.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

Here is the test.json contents:

```
{ "Days" : [
    {
        "Date": "04-04-13",
        "Price": "1.61"
    },
    {
        "Date": "04-11-13",
        "Price": "1.61"
    }  
    ]
}
```

Any help much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% *sure* the file is in the same folder as the script is running in?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your `test1.json` file contains a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Use the `encoding` parameter for [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). Use actual encoding of your file; if I can **only guess** [`UTF-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` as follows:

```
import json

path_to_file='D:\\Python\\SO3\\data\\test1.json'

with open(path_to_file, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

**Output**: `D:\Python\SO3\61667193.py`

```
{'Days': [{'Price': '1.61', 'Date': '04-04-13'}, {'Price': '1.61', 'Date': '04-11-13'}]}
```

---

**Note**: You can *detect* real encoding/BOM using the following [function by ivan_pozdeev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370596/3439404):

```
def detect_by_bom(path,default):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        raw = f.read(4)    #will read less if the file is smaller
    for enc,boms in \
            ('utf-8-sig',(codecs.BOM_UTF8,)),\
            ('utf-16',(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE,codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE)),\
            ('utf-32',(codecs.BOM_UTF32_LE,codecs.BOM_UTF32_BE)):
        if any(raw.startswith(bom) for bom in boms): return enc
    return default
```

Comment: Gosh sorry I did not reply at the time, you were spot on and solved my issues. Thank you very much!