# Python 3.5 cannot read a file with special character ★

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, pycharm

i have below code in python 3.5 [screen of IDE and powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKOvw.png)

```
real_path_log_file = 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\report\\file1.log'
with open(real_path_log_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as open_log:
    read_log = open_log.readlines()
    print(read_log)
```

from powershell i get below error but if i run this from pycharm i can getting the output of file content
please note that file i am reading has ★ character

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test_read_file.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(read_log)
  File "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 367: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Are pycharm and powershell using the same instance/install of python?

Comment: from pycharm i can see that "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe" interpeter is selected.
how can i check it from powershell ?

Comment: i did below in power shell. Does this help ?
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python35\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages', '

Comment: What does `python -V` say in both prompts?  That's capital `V`.

Comment: its printing Python 3.5.0

Comment: Thank you js2010. yes printing was the issue. hence i started writing the output to text file for my validation and i could see the correct text written to my text file

Also below post of the same topic helped me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590749/reading-unicode-file-data-with-bom-chars-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I'm no python expert. At least in 3.5, I think print() needs to believe that the console can support unicode characters.  For what it's worth, 3.8.5 doesn't have this problem.